# How do I tell pyinstaller to use python-certifi-win32 with --onefile option

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a small scirpt which is using the tableau rest api to download data from tableau views. As the script is running in a corporate environment, I have to use SSL. That's where the [python-certifi-win32](https://pypi.org/project/python-certifi-win32/) package comes into play. Installing the package with `pip install python-certifi-win32` patches the certifi package to use the local machine certificate store. From the documentation:

> This package patches certifi at runtime to also include certificates from the windows certificate store.

This works perfectly fine when I run the script from source, but if I create an executable using pyinstaller (with the `--onefile` option), the "patch at runtime" does not seem to happen and I get a "local certificate could not be validated" error, which is the same that I got before installing the python-certifi-win32 package.

As I am fairly new to Python, I could not figure out how exactly the python-certifi-win32 package does the "patch at runtime". I already tried with the `--hidden-import` option but that did not work.

Any suggestion how to tell pyinstaller (or my script) to apply the "python-certifi-win32 magic" when called as executable?

Comment: python-certifi-win32 has been replaced by [pip-system-certs](https://pypi.org/project/pip-system-certs/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't need to mess with hidden imports, but you will need to import the library itself.

The package loses some of its auto-magic when executing in PyInstaller's runtime setup. Resolving this depends on where you need the winstore certs, but this is what I do to get it working where I need it for `requests`:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    import certifi_win32
    os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = certifi_win32.wincerts.where()
    certifi_win32.generate_pem()
```

Setting `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` will point requests to use the store that certifi_win32 creates. the `generate_pem` function will union the certificate bundle that is shipped with PyInstaller (located in `<MEIPASS>\certifi`) and the wincert store. The resulting `pem` file is written to `%LOCALAPPDATA%/.certifi/cacert.pem`.