# Requests SSL validation - only use windows certificate store when creating exe via Pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

### Background

Related recent question:  [How do I tell pyinstaller to use python-certifi-win32 with --onefile option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67803957/how-do-i-tell-pyinstaller-to-use-python-certifi-win32-with-onefile-option)

I'm creating an application for clients that is using `requests` to make HTTPS connections outbound to several AWS hosted applications.
My clients are using Windows 10, so I'm using `pyinstaller` to create single-file exe's as the distribution/deployment model.

### Use Case and Problem

- The clients are often behind corporate firewalls, so using custom SSL certificates.
- I don't want to have to force my users to have to update my app frequently simply if SSL certificates are updated in `certifi`.
- I don't want to use (or be responsible for) a separate CA store in my app different to what the clients might be using (and/or their IT dept specifying) in their OS level certificate store

--> So basically I want requests to only use the OS's (in this case specifically Windows) certificate store, and not provide/distribute any separate ones (ie via certifi).

---

### Observation

This seems to be a common use case, and a common problem people have - but one *without* any easy solution (or at least anything mentioned/discussed/documented as part of the `requests` documention and/or urllib3's).

The requests concept of 'hey - we'll use our own cert store separate to the OS' has some pros and cons.  ...In this use case it doesn't fit too well though.

---

### Naive (?) Solution

I'm by no means a web or `requests` expert, so after researching as much as I could it seems like the best thing to do is to tell `requests` to get all certificates it uses for SSL validation from the Windows Certificate store, and not use those in `certifi`.

### Naive (?) Question

How do you tell `requests` to a) use the Windows certificate store to get certificates and b) *only* use certificates from there (and so not use any provided by `certifi`.

- There seems to be a module for this [python-certifi-win32](https://pypi.org/project/python-certifi-win32/#history), but it seems to be old and perhaps not maintained.  ...however is that what I should be using?
- The documentation from python-certifi-win32 and what I could find with some searching indicates that this only *adds* the windows store certificates to any already got from `certifi`, not *replace*.  ...is that correct?  ...if correct, how would you go about *only* using those from python-certifi-win32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`python-certifi-win32` loses some of its auto-magic when executing in PyInstaller's runtime setup. This is what I do to get it working:

```
if sys.platform == 'win32':
    import certifi_win32
    os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = certifi_win32.wincerts.where()
    certifi_win32.generate_pem()
```

Setting `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` will point requests to use the store that certifi_win32 creates. the `generate_pem` function will union the certificate bundle that is shipped with PyInstaller (located in `<MEIPASS>\certifi`) and the wincert store. The resulting `pem` file is written to `%LOCALAPPDATA%/.certifi/cacert.pem`. It should properly verify your endpoints if you have the right certs in the store.

Comment: **Note:** [python-certifi-win32](https://pypi.org/project/python-certifi-win32/) has been deprecated and the author suggests using [pip-system-certs](https://pypi.org/project/pip-system-certs/) instead.